# gulp end callback not called

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-babel

I'm having trouble setting up a simple task on gulp. I want to pass the files through `gulp-babel` to run a script, but the `end` callback is never called.

I also tried `finish`. The only callback called is `data`, but it doesn't work for me because I need to run it after all the files ran through babel.

`gulp-debug` shows the files have been correctly found.

Any toughts?

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var gulp = require('gulp'),
        babel = require('gulp-babel'),
        debug = require('gulp-debug');


    gulp.task('parseReviews', function () {
        gulp.src(['scripts/parseReviews.js', 'src/**/*.js'])
        .pipe(debug())
        .pipe(babel())
        .on('end', function () {
            const foo = require('../../scripts/parseReviews');
            console.log(foo);
        });
    });
})();
```

Comment: Did you try to catch the 'error' event in order to be sure that no error occurred while running your pipeline?  https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_error

Comment: Are you sure that this pattern `'src/**/*.js'` does not pick a huge number of files? Try to run it and open a task manager (top in case of linux) and check if gulp is present there. If you are able to see it in the task manager and it is working really hard, then it is quite possible that this pattern is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Reuven. I just tried and the error callback is not called.

Comment: Svabael, I used gulp-debug to see the files, it's a small project and it brings only 22 files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `return` your stream from your task:

```
gulp.task('parseReviews', function () {
  return gulp.src(['scripts/parseReviews.js', 'src/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(babel())
    .on('end', function () {
        const foo = require('../../scripts/parseReviews');
        console.log(foo);
    });
});
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Now I have to figure out why I'm still getting `unexpected token import` despite calling babel before. But thats unrelated to the question.